# Should I substitute my missing data before or after reversing my items?

Tags: dataset, missing-data

Good evening,
I'm having a doubt about how treat my data: I've some missing data and I'd like to fill them with the mean, but some of my items need to be reversed.
So I was wondering should I reverse my items and then calculate the mean? Or should I calculate the mean and only then I can substitute my missing data with the mean?
Thank you all

Comment: Select a set of random points from your data whose value is known. Look at naive forecasting models assuming these points are indeed missing. For example, try the nearest neighbor as a predictor, or the average of nearest neighbors or the overall sample mean as a point estimate. The naive model producing the smallest defined average error over the selected data set would be my choice. Could repeat with other point selections for validation.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you recode your data first and then take the mean, or take the mean first and then recode should not make any difference at all, simply because

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(ax_i+b) = a\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\bigg)+b $$

(with $a=-1$ and $b=0$).

---

Note that filling missing data with the mean will drop all the uncertainty that is definitely present in your data. You will be too sure of your conclusions, whatever they are. There are smarter ways to impute missing data, and I personally believe that rather than imputing the mean, you are probably better off if you delete observations with missing data casewise. See also [Does imputation introduce unacceptable bias?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/483698/1352)